# 5 beeps with Xeon E3-1230L V3 installed?

Tags: xeon

I've bought a Xeon E3-1230LV3 1.8 GHz CPU, and a Asus H97M Plus motherboard. When I power it up it makes five short beeps. I tested the motherboard with a different Core i7 and a Celeron, and both work fine, so I assumed I had fried the CPU. I therefore bought another Xeon E3-1230LV3, but it has the same issue (five short beeps).

Here's a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/PEozEZWf4UU

From [Asus's website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H97MPLUS/HelpDesk_CPU/) it looks like the CPU should be compatible, but I can't find anything on Intel's website. Does anyone know if the CPU is vendor locked, and in that case, to which motherboards?

Comment: Is this for a server?

Comment: Just a home server, hence the desktop motherboard.

Comment: You link says you need a minimum of BIOS revision 0303 to use that XEON - which revision is currently installed on that board?  BTW I've never seen a 'vendor-locked' Intel desktop/server CPU -- I don't think they exist.

Comment: BIOS is version 2602

Comment: This processor has no GPU. Do you have a dedicated GPU installed?

Comment: Daniel: No, but there's an HDMI plug in the motherboard. Doesn't that mean that there's a display controller built into the motherboard?

Comment: Where on Earth did you buy it? It is almost impossible to get this CPU model. A few ppl are selling it on ebay, but I would not trust them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel B was right in his comment above. The Xeon does not have a built in GPU.

It worked after I installed a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds the BIOS is not up to date - the minimum version is 0303. In addition 3 beeps only is not listed as an option in the manual - is there a long beep prior to the 3 short once? If yes that would indicate issues with VGA, rather than fried CPU:

> One continuous beep followed by threeshort beeps - No VGA detected
>
> One continuous beep followed by fourshort beeps - Hardware component
>   failure

Comment: BIOS was version 2502 from the factory, and I have just tried updating to 2602. Same result :-( VGA seems fine, as the motherboard works fine with a Celeron and an i7.

Comment: Sp what is the reason you don't upgrade to the 0303 with the celeron in the board?

Comment: 2502 and 2602 are newer than 0303.